# Android listview postition sequence wrong

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview of about 20 item. each row of adapter have a image button which do different action when i click it. when i click item of the listview, i managed to get position number correctly. but when i click the image button, the position i got is wrong. Instead of 0~19, but it showed 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 .....

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;        

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView     = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_video, null);
        holder          = new ViewHolder();

        holder.rlContainer      = (RelativeLayout)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.rlContainer);
        holder.imageView        = (ImageView)       convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivLogo);
        holder.buttonBackground = (ImageView)       convertView.findViewById(R.id.ibButtonLebih);
        holder.tvtitle          = (TextView)        convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);

        holder.buttonBackground.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {               
                videoListClickListener.OnVideoMoreClickListener(position);
            }
        });

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: You should place the setTag outside of the if/else statement
see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5197476/661079

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue solved! by moving onclicklistener and setTag to outside of if/else.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
ViewHolder holder;        

if (convertView == null) {
    convertView     = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_video, null);
    holder          = new ViewHolder();

    holder.rlContainer      = (RelativeLayout)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.rlContainer);
    holder.imageView        = (ImageView)       convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivLogo);
    holder.buttonBackground = (ImageView)       convertView.findViewById(R.id.ibButtonLebih);
    holder.tvtitle          = (TextView)        convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);

} else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}

holder.buttonBackground.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {               
            videoListClickListener.OnVideoMoreClickListener(position);
        }
    });

    convertView.setTag(holder);


return convertView;
```

}