# OnClickListener for image within listview with OnItemClickListener

Tags: android, listview

I have got a list view of contacts with profile image as well. I have `OnItemClickListener` on this list view.

Within a single list view item, for the image, I have an `OnClickListener` (for changing the profile image). Both these listeners are working fine.

My concern is:
When this profile image is clicked, can I get the position of the image/contact within the list view ? Since, when image is clicked `OnClick` will be called which does not give us the 
position within list view. How to get the position ?

I checked that when the image `OnClick` is getting fired then `OnItemClick` is not getting fired and vice-versa as well.

Comment: See here How can I get the position of the item within a listview when I click on a specific view?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get the position of the item within a listview when I click on a specific view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197428/how-can-i-get-the-position-of-the-item-within-a-listview-when-i-click-on-a-speci)